# Why rosdep install doesn't work?

Tags: rosdep, ros-hydro, rosdep-install, aria, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to install the rosaria package trough rosdep but when I run the command rosdep install rosaria along this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA) this is what I obtain :

```
robotics@robotics-MacBookAir:~/catkin_ws/src$ rosdep install rosaria
Executing script below with cwd=/tmp
{{{
#!/bin/bash
if test "x`dpkg-query -W -f='${Package} ${Status} ${Version}\n' libaria-sourcedep`" != 'xlibaria-sourcedep install ok installed 2.8.0-1'; then
 echo "libaria-sourcedep not installed"
  exit 1
else
  exit 0
fi

}}}

#All required rosdeps installed successfully
robotics@robotics-MacBookAir:~/catkin_ws/src$
```

And then if I try to run: `rosrun rosaria RosAria`, nothing happen and it crashes.

UPDATE:

This is what I obtain when I run :

```
roscd && cd ../src
cd ..
catkin_make

git clone https://github.com/amor-ros-pkg/rosaria.git
robotics@robotics-MacBookAir:~/catkin_ws/src$ roscd && cd ../src
robotics@robotics-MacBookAir:~/catkin_ws/src$ git clone https://github.com/amor-ros-pkg/rosaria.git
fatal: destination path 'rosaria' already exists and is not an empty directory.
robotics@robotics-MacBookAir:~/catkin_ws/src$ cd ..
robotics@robotics-MacBookAir:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/robotics/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/robotics/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/robotics/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/robotics/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/robotics/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/robotics/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/robotics/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [ 16%] Built target rosaria_gencfg
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 16%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 16%] [ 16%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 16%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 33%] Built target rosaria_generate_messages_cpp
[ 50%] Built target rosaria_generate_messages_lisp
[ 83%] Built target rosaria_generate_messages_py
[ 83%] Built target rosaria_gencpp
[ 83%] Built target rosaria_generate_messages
[100%] Built target RosAria
robotics@robotics-MacBookAir:~/catkin_ws$
```

Do you have an idea about what would be the cause of this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213228/why-rosdep-install-doesn%27t-work?/) by [vince](https://answers.ros.org/users/21818/vince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's not actually installing ROSAria. You need to compile the source. Run the following.

```
$ roscd && cd ../src
$ git https://github.com/amor-ros-pkg/rosaria.git
$ cd ../ && catkin_make
```

But, as a side note, you can use `p2os` to work with Pioneer robots by using `apt-get`.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-jade-p2os-*
```

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2015-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vince](https://answers.ros.org/users/21818/vince/) on 2015-07-08**:
Thank you for the reply, I've already try git clone https://github.com/amor-ros-pkg/rosar... then catkin_make but when I do rosrun rosaria RosAria nothing at all happens. I wonder it was because of rosdep.

**Comment by [vince](https://answers.ros.org/users/21818/vince/) on 2015-07-08**:
I also tried sudo apt-get install ros-jade-p2os-*, it seems working but I get errors. I need to fix that but I would prefer working with RosAria since I use to.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-07-09**:
Could you update your question with the output of the relevant commands? I also might suggest you run `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` and try ROSAria again. But if you're getting errors with p2os, please let me know, as I'm the p2os maintainer.

**Comment by [vince](https://answers.ros.org/users/21818/vince/) on 2015-07-09**:
I have already source after catkin_make, in that case it does not find the package but here, it finds it but nothing about even that it cannot find the master.
For p2os I have already fix it, but I am wondering if I need p2os_dashboard package because it does not exist.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-07-09**:
You do not need `p2os_dashboard`. I'm actually planning to completely redo that program. But it is not anywhere close to a necessity. Unfortunately, I cannot help much with ROSAria.